# __no_operation invalid in C99 IAR 9.20.4

Tags: c, stm32, iar, stm32f0

I've an old code that perfectly works in IAR IAR 7.60

I would like to port it to IAR 9.20.4. The only issue while compiling is that I got a  `__no_operation();` line of code that generates an error while compiling

IAR reports the error as

```
Error[Li005]: no definition for "__no_operation" [referenced from C:\[...]\EWARM\F041701a_beta000\Obj\Application\User\93c66.o]
```

And also got a warning

```
Warning: implicit declaration of function '__no_operation' is invalid in C99
```

Is there a way to work around, resolve the issue?

I can't find a solution at the moment.

I'm using an STM32F0

Comment: You are misreading the warning message. It does not tell you that `__no_operation` is invalid as you state in your title. It tells you that *implicit declarations* are invalid. There must be some header to include for your toolset that brings the required prototypes for intrinsic functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `__iar_builtin_no_operation();` instead of `__no_operation();` fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

you need to add to your program:

```
#include "intrinsics.h"
```

Which defines this inline function.